# Left key postion not returning correct value on safari mac system?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When i am going to differentiate the shift key stroke on keyboard event, apple safari browser does not produce correct position to find out which key i am typing now whether it is left or right shift key. Is there any possibility to get the correct position value? But in case of other browsers produce one, two value for both keys respectively.

Comment: Why do you need to know which shift key was used? They both normally perform the same function, are basically interchangeable – and users are used to that behavior. So anything that tries to make them perform different functionalities is likely a UX fail to begin with.

Comment: Basically i need to show the difference image based on left and right shit keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**use this to get left and right shift it's working in Mac Safari also**

```
if ( e.keyCode == 16 ) {
     if (e.originalEvent.location === KeyboardEvent.DOM_KEY_LOCATION_LEFT){
               console.log('left Shift')
          }
    else if (e.originalEvent.location === KeyboardEvent.DOM_KEY_LOCATION_RIGHT){
     console.log('right Shift')
    }
}
```